# delete border on button when the user click

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I need to delete border where the user focus/click on the button. this is My hhtml element:

```
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <button mat-icon-button  class="modifyButton" >
                                 <mat-icon >arrow_right_alt</mat-icon>
                               </button>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
```

In my scss I do this:

```
.modifyButton:focus,
.modifyButton:active {
    border: none;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone can help to eliminate border when the user click on the button?

Comment: where you defined this scss?

Comment: It worked fine for me, maybe your scss is not getting selected by yout template